# Parse through Subdirectories, skip base directory

Tags: batch-file

Good day, everyone!

So I have this structure in my html archives:

```
base folder\
       \Subject 1
           index.html
       \Subject 2
           index.html
```

... and so on. Now I want the batch to round up all those index.htmls in the subdirs and put them into a linked TOC.html in the base folder. Also, the names of those subdirs should be named as link titles, otherwise its only ever "index.html". Like so:

```
Subject 1
Subject 2
```

(Those would be links to the index.htmls in the folders, then.)

The Batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo ^<html^> > toc
echo ^<meta charset="utf-8"^> >> toc
for /R . %%i in (index.html) do (
  set "B=%%i"
  set "C=!B:%CD%\=!"
  echo ^<a href=".\!C!"^>!C:~0,-11%!^</a^> ^<br/^> >> toc
)
echo ^</html^> >> toc
del toc.html
ren toc toc.html
```

As of now, the batch file is just being copied into "\base folder" to run. The two variables are only used to make that long command line a bit shorter, and to be able to subtract further from the strings, because for the titles, the last 11 tokens (as in "\index.html") are being subtracted. And it's working too, the produced TOC.html looks like this:

```
<html> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<a href=".\index.html"></a> <br/> 
<a href=".\Subject 1\index.html">Subject 1</a> <br/> 
<a href=".\Subject 2\index.html">Subject 2</a> <br/> 
</html>
```

Only problem is that first line "<a href" though: The batch looks for an index.html in its own base folder, where there isn't (supposed to be) one. How can I make the batch file look exclusively into the subdirs?

Thanks for any and all help!

Best,

Schöpke

Comment: `for /R . %%i in (index.html) do if /i "%%~dpi" NEQ "%CD%\" (` should execute the body of the loop if (`/i` case insensitive) the drive+path of the file is **N**ot**EQ**ual to the current directoryname+a terminal backslash.

Comment: Genius! That was it! Thanks a lot, @Magoo!